# Disable sudo password and ask yes or no like in Windows

Tags: sudo, password

Every time I install new software in Ubuntu Software Center, it asks me for my password.
I don't want to disable the authentication because it won't ask me for the password if I click on something accidentally.
I want it to ask me yes or no like in Windows user account control when a program asks for administrator access.
[image]

Comment: There is no easy way for a new user to accomplish this behavior. Ubuntu simply works *differently*. For example, even with a Yes/No dialog, you would STILL need to input an admin password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important to note that Ubuntu will never be like Windows. Ubuntu is it's own OS and if you prefer windows features then you should install windows.

That being said, you can configure Ubuntu to never ask you for a sudo password.

Open terminal and type:

```
sudo visudo
```

In the bottom of the file, add the following line:

```
$USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Where $USER is your username on your system. Save and close the sudoers file.

When you install programs from terminal, it will still confirm whether you want to install it or not but you won't have to input your password.

Comment: Thank you for responding fast. I already have Windows installed. Ubuntu is my secondary OS. And I meant installing software from the Ubuntu software center, not from the command line.

Comment: @adazem009 Thanks for clearing that up. If you just make sure not to install the incorrect software from the software center you should be good. However, if you do accidently install something, you can always uninstall.